# Statistical and systematic error

Tags: definition, error-analysis, statistics

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10459.pdf), but in many others too, we see a result presented as

$$ ... = 16.84\pm0.16(stat)\pm0.20(syst).$$

How are these two errors calculated? Is there a single algorithm to calculate these from a data set of $n$ samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statistical error is calculated from the size of the sample and various measures of how it might (statistically) vary.  There's no single formula for that, but there are a few well-recognized methods: Poisson statistics for small numbers of events, normal (Gaussian) statistics for large numbers of samples from a single distribution, etc.  The statistical error basically tracks the possibility of random fluctuations during the measurement:  More measurements make it go down (generally)

Systematic errors are *not* due to random processes in the measurement itself. They're there to capture the chance of making a mistake during that measurement.  Is your voltmeter perfectly calibrated? You did the best you could (hopefully) but it's not a perfect instrument. These are inevitably judgement calls.  We often make secondary measurements to check for possible systematic errors, but those are imperfect too.  For example, in the linked paper:

> The systematic uncertainties was estimated by taking into account the uncertainty of the target position along the beam line, which was estimated to be ± 2 mm, which may cause mXc2± 0.06 MeV uncertainty. The uncertainty of the place of the beam spot perpendicular to the beam axis was estimated to be in worst case also ± 2 mm, which may cause a shift in the invariant mass of mX c2 ± 0.15 MeV/c2 . The whole systematic error was conservatively estimated as: mXc2±0.20 MeV.

So in the end, you try to make as good a measurement as you can, and quantify your uncertainty in the systematic error.